# I want to list all media Categories in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have tired of googling that how I can list all media Categories in WordPress.

Any Idea? Also after getting the media category list, i would like to display the media associated with each category.

Thanks
Shubhajeet Saha

Comment: You mean from Categories audio,vedio,images in all media?

Comment: No Categories like Hills, Beaches, Forests etc.

Comment: suppose your parent category is media  in any custom post type and you want to get list of child of those?

Comment: if you good explain me i can slove your problem

Comment: Well check the link [link](http://koncept.org.in/gallery/gallery.html). I have added a plugin media-category to add categories to the images. I want to create gallery like given link where whenever categories are added tabs increases. And gallery will be populated like the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'hide_empty'=> 0,
    'child_of' => 10, //Child From Boxes Category 
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
print_r($categories);
```

Actually this plugin is simply added category option from default post to media. so you can get category easily with multiple method. goto this link
[How to display my all category names using loop (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631655/how-to-display-my-all-category-names-using-loop-wordpress)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Sajid, I solved like this: 
<?php $args = array( 'orderby' => 'id',  'hide_empty'=> 0,   'exclude' => 1,   'exclude_tree' =>  1,    );
  $categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach ($categories as $cat) {       echo '<li><a data-filter=".'.$cat->name.' href="#">'.$cat->name.'</a></li>';        }
?>

But am still looking for solution to fetch media with its category name which has a category assigned to it and want to Order by media upload date ASC.